# Detect wall corner with openCV - Hard

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, corner-detection

I have this image (sorry for the size): [image: wall corner]

Edit: this is just a simple wall corner of my room, nothing special...

I'm trying to detect the exactly corner, but so far failed to do so.
I try to use gray and bilateral, mask and canny and of course combinations of some openCV corner algorithms like Harris, EigenValsAndVecs, MinEigenVal and more...
So far, I found a lot of points, or none.
Any idea please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems rather straightforward. First you compute the gradient magnitude, which will find the lines in between the three mostly uniform regions (`b` in the image below), and then you apply something like the Harris corner detector (or any other variety will work too) to find the intersection point between the straight lines (`c` in the image below). I used a sigma of 4 for both the Gaussian gradient magnitude and the smoothing in the Harris detector.

[image: output]

I did this test quickly in MATLAB, because it was open, but you have access to the same [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) algorithms I used (disclosure: I'm an author of DIPlib). It would look something like this:

```py
import diplib as dip

a = dip.ImageRead('corner.jpg') # you can use OpenCV or PIL or whatever else for reading too

b = dip.GradientMagnitude(a, sigmas=4)
c = dip.HarrisCornerDetector(b, sigmas=4)
```

Comment: thnx! very helpful!

Comment: Hi @Cris: I tried running the code on the same image,, but getting an error while applying Haariscorner detection  c = dip.HarrisCornerDetector(b, sigmas=4).   The error is :: RuntimeError: Image is not scalar
in function: HarrisCornerDetector (diplib\diplib\src\detection\corners.cpp at line number 34)

Comment: @Satya It requires a scalar image (i.e. gray-scale, not color). If `ImageRead` returns a color image, you can for example just use the green channel: `a = a(1)`.